# Java Float value Formatting with two decimal places

Tags: java

Following are my codes to add two values

```
float ptoTotalAmount = 0;
Map<String, String> renewalDetailview = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
String Fee = driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath("//div[@data-bind='html: CURRenewalFees']"))
                .getText().substring(4).replace(",", "");       
        ptoTotalAmount += Float.valueOf((ptoFee));
        String surcharge = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-bind='html: Surcharges']"))
                .getText().substring(4).replace(",", "");       
        ptoTotalAmount += Float.valueOf((surcharge));

        renewalDetailview.put("totalfee", Float.toString(ptoTotalAmount));
```

For an Example:

Fee - 31500.00,surcharge - 1500.00

Fee + surcharge = 33000.00

Thus, expected result for totalfee - 33000.00, but I'm getting 33000.0

Therefore, I applied Formatting to my float value with 2 decimal places, but I'm not getting expected result.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        renewalDetailview.put("totalfee", String.valueOf(df.format(ptoTotalAmount)));
```

I'm getting 330,00 something like this, please help me to format with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Please stop using `float` and `double` for currency calculations

Comment: Don't do `String.valueOf` just keep `df.format(ptoTotalAmount).toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
float value = 33000.00f;//float??
String formattedString = String.format( "%.2f", value);
System.out.println(formattedString);
Output:
33000.00
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to model currency.
If so, you should check the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)